# SFML Audio getSample in realtime using sf::Music

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

Is there any way to read the current sample that's been playing in sf::Music for further inspection using FFT algorithms and such?

Just like you would do using sf::SoundBuffer with getSamples().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. But considering you'll want a significant portion of your file (or maybe everything) in memory anyway, just use `sf::SoundBuffer` and `sf::Sound` for this.

To get the sample for the current playback position you'd have to do some calculation like `samplesPerSecond * playbackPosition`. Just interpolate the time between the last and current calculation.